# Modifying a subject, or an object

Tags: relative-clauses, reduced-relative-clauses

- Generally, patterns are produced in weft knitted structures either in the form of selected colours for face stitches or surface relief patterns **based on** a choice of different types of stitch.

This sentence has been taken from **Knitting Technology** by **David J Spencer**. Which is modified by **based on**? One may think that without an expert of knitting technology it is not possible to say actually which has been modified by **based on**. I will request him/her to consider it from the point of grammatical view. In my opinion, **based on** is modifying both **face stitches** and **relief patterns**. It is not modifying only **relief patterns**. If the writer hoped to indicate only **relief patterns**, he might write the sentence in the following way:

- Generally, patterns are produced in weft knitted structures either in the form of selected colours for face stitches or surface relief patterns **that is** based on a choice of different types of stitch.

But this is wrong. Because we cannot use **that is** or **which is**, because **relief patterns** is in plural form. If we use **which are**, still now it is ambiguous. Because **which are** is capable to refer to both **face stitches** and **relief patterns**. I don't know how to rewrite the above sentence if I wish to refer only **relief patterns** or **face stitches**, and how to rewrite if I want to refer both of them.

If I write the sentence in the following way, **based on** refers only **patterns** (patterns are produced...) that is the subject of the above sentence.

- Generally, patterns are produced in weft knitted structures either in the form of selected colours for face stitches or surface relief patterns, based on a choice of different types of stitch.

OR

- Generally, patterns are produced in weft knitted structures either in the form of selected colours for face stitches or surface relief patterns, which is based on a choice of different types of stitch.

Please give your valuable opinion.

Comment: Generally, patterns (insert extra words for context) are based on **a choice of different types of stitch**. IE: your chosen type of stitch helps determine your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in this case, **based on** refers to **surface relief patterns**. The sentence talks about different **patterns** and how they are produced on a **textile product**. Two possibilities are given, one using **colour** and the other using **texture**.

The alternative for **colour** is clearly given by

> **selected colours for face stitches**

and the alternative for **texture** is given by

> **surface relief patterns**

which are created using

> **different types of stitch**

One way to make **based on** in the sentence unambiguous is to fill in the parallel construction of the **either..or**

> Generally, patterns are produced in weft knitted structures **either** in the form of selected colours for face stitches **or** ***in the form of*** surface relief patterns based on a choice of different types of stitch.

[NB: I'm not a tailor, but possibly **face stitches** should be **facing stitches**?]

Answer (score 0):

This is not an elegant or well-phrased sentence.

But it breaks down like so:

> "patterns are produced..."
>
> "**either** in the form of selected colours for face stitches"
>
> "**or** [by] surface relief patterns *based on* a choice of different types of stitch".